# How to deploy local MySQL database to Heroku using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I'm new to using Heroku and I have a nodejs app in which I plan on using a MySQL database as the main data store and please tell me how setup mysql in heroku

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an add-on for this. There is one for MySQL provided by [ClearDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb).